# FFPMEG command to record screen works only from cmd on windows but not from my Java class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ffmpeg

i have a JUNIT test that uses a Java class called ScreenRecordingWatcher where i specified my ffpmeg command to record the computer when my test fails.

But unfortunately, my command only works from my cmd and not from my class, On both sides it generates successfully my file, but when it is generated from my Java class, the file is not readable from my windows player (0xc10100be error).

Here is the command i am using :

```
C:\outils\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\bin\ffmpeg.exe -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -c:v h264_nvenc -qp 0 C:\outils\video\output.mkv
```

Here is the same command from my class :

```
public class ScreenRecordingWatcher extends TestWatcher {

private static final String FFMPEG_PATH = "C:\\outils\\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe";
private static final String OUTPUT_FILE = "C:\\outils\\video\\fichier.mkv";
private boolean testFailed = false;

@Override
protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {

    super.failed(e, description);
    testFailed = true;
}

@Override
protected void finished(Description description) {
    super.finished(description);
    if (testFailed) {
        startRecording();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        stopRecording();
    }
}

private void startRecording() {
    String[] command = { FFMPEG_PATH, "-f", "gdigrab", "-framerate", "30", "-i", "desktop", "-c:v", "h264_nvenc", "-qp", "0", OUTPUT_FILE };

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(command));
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    try {
        builder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void stopRecording() {
    String[] command = { "tskill", "ffmpeg" };
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    try {
        builder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

Does someone have an idea of why it executes well from my cmd but not from my class ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that when you execute a command from the command line, the current working directory and environment variables are typically set to the user's home directory and system environment, respectively.

However, when executing a command from Java using ProcessBuilder, the working directory and environment variables may be different. By default, ProcessBuilder uses the current working directory of the Java process, which may not be the same as the directory where your ffmpeg executable is located.

So specified my directory as below :

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.directory(new File("C:\\outils\\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\\bin")); // Set the working directory
```